# Maintain data frame structure while update date/time value for a column

Tags: r, datetime

I have a dataset with the following fields:

```
a. Date: formatted as a character field - mm/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss AM/PM (character field)
b. X: pressure guage reading in PSI (numeric field)
```

Sample data:

| Date | X |
| --- | --- |
| 7/13/2022 5:15:59 AM | 0.00 |
| 7/13/2022 5:20:00 AM | 1.50 |
| 7/15/2022 1:00:00 PM | 4.00 |

I changed the format of the "Date" column to a 24-hour date/time format using the following R code: as.POSIXct(df$Date, format="%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p", tz="UTC"). Although the output of the code was correct, the table did not change.

I tried using the following code:

```
df$[df$Date] <- as.POSIXct(df$Date, format="%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p", tz="UTC")
```

but that produced an error message:

> Warning: NAs produced by integer overflowWarning: NAs produced by integer overflowError in if (m < n * p && (m == 0L || (n * p)%%m)) stop(sprintf(ngettext(m,  :
> missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

How do I update just the date column while also keeping the table format?

In other words, the result should appear as:

| New_Date | X |
| --- | --- |
| 7/13/2022 5:15:59 | 0.00 |
| 7/13/2022 5:20:00 | 1.50 |
| 7/15/2022 13:00:00 | 4.00 |

Comment: I don't get a warning message using your code on this sample data.

Comment: r2evans - Hmm...I'm not sure why it did for me. That's strange.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
dt$Date = strptime(dt$Date, format="%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p", tz="UTC")
```

```
                 Date   x
1 2022-07-13 05:15:59 0.0
2 2022-07-13 05:20:00 1.5
3 2022-07-15 13:00:00 4.0
```

FYI that will converts Date to class `POSIXlt`. If you want it in `POSIXct` you can wrap `as.POSIXct()` around it.

Comment: Jamie - thank you. Yes, it is what I'm looking for. Your response helped me see the error in my initial code attempt.

Comment: No problem! I'm assuming it's linked to this? `df$[df$Date]`

Comment: Sigh...yes, typo!